# Batch Apex to update field in lead object

Tags: apex, batch

I want to update lead source field to say Dream force on all of my leads. following is the code that I have developed. for some reason it is not going inside for loop.

```
global class LeadProcessor implements Database.Batchable<sObject>, Database.Stateful {

global Integer recordsProcessed = 0;


global database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    system.debug('Start called');
    return Database.getQueryLocator([Select Id,LeadSource from Lead]);
}
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc,List<Lead> scope){
    system.debug('Entered in Execute');
    List <Lead> leads = new List<Lead>();       
    for(Lead lead : leads)
    {
        system.debug('Entered in for loop');
        lead.LeadSource = 'Dreamforce';
        recordsProcessed = recordsProcessed + 1;
    }
    update leads;
}
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){

}
}
```

can any one help explain what can I do to achieve above usecase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo:

```
List <Lead> leads = new List<Lead>();       
    for(Lead lead : leads)
```

Which means leads is just instantiated and is empty.

Change `leads` to `scope` which is the parameter passed into that method as a result of the query.

Comment: I did that, Now it is going through the for loop but not updating leads. As statement says update leads. What do I need to change that with so it updates value back for the field LeadSource in the record?

Comment: Again, updating the wrong variable. Update `scope` instead.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through the `scope` variable and finally update the `scope`

```
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc,List<Lead> scope){
    system.debug('Entered in Execute');
    for(Lead lead : scope)
    {
        system.debug('Entered in for loop');
        lead.LeadSource = 'Dreamforce';
        recordsProcessed = recordsProcessed + 1;
    }
    update scope;
}
```